# WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 - Android device registered but no device on console

Tags: android, wso2-iot

I've installed WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 on a personnal server and I followed the configuration on the official documentation.
After adding certificate (from let's encrypt), generating BKS file and making my own APK, I've registered my Android phone and I've got the following (on phone) :

```
Device successfully registered, click to unregister from the EMM
```

But when I log on my console (https://mydomain:9443/emm) I got 0 devices registered.

Does anyone know what I missed ?

Thanks.

Comment: .Witch version of wso2 emm are you working on ?What are credentials used to enrolled the device and log in to the emm console. are they the same ? what are the roles associated to the related users.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer.
I'm working on EMM 2.0.1
I've created a brand new account to enroll my device with "admin" role.
I log in the emm console both with my new account and with the "admin" account and I still got no device.
I've just noticed a new issue, when I trie to make a new role nothing is created (without error message).

Comment: Can you check the functionalities with the admin:admin credentials and check. And please provide your environment details in order to try checking your problem by reproducing.

Comment: Same issue with the admin:admin credentials .... My environment is the following : 
- Debian 7.6 
- JRE 1.7.0

Comment: When I check the database I can see neither devices nor roles, (instead of admin role). I can create users but nothing more ...

Comment: Nobody got an idea about the issue ?

Comment: Did you mount the registry properly?https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer.

I've totaly removed WSO2 EMM in order to start with a brand new and clean installation. Actually I can make roles but I got the same issue with the Android devices. I think the problem may be in the android APK used to enroll the phone. I gonna search for other sources, build a new APK and try again.

@GPrathap : I've not installed WSO2 G-Reg, I only got WSO2 EMM. I've not seen that WSO2 G-Reg is a pre-requisit for EMM, am I wrong ?